# k8s cron job using helm chart and docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cron, ansible, helm

Two Helm chart for managing db cron jobs and monitoring cron jobs separately . Which k8s components can i use ? as k8s deprecated CronJob kind from v1.25, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#v1-25  . Please share example and also how to test in my environment .

Comment: You are misreading that document. Kubernetes did not deprecate CronJobs. They deprecated the `batch/v1beta1` API; all CronJobs should now use the `batch/v1` API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.